# Fatal Exception: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment

I was following Android Youtube Api (ListVideos) which is in `Activity`. I'm trying this in `Fragment` and I'm getting FATAL EXCEPTION `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` I gone through some answers posted by others. It couldn't help me. Could anyone tell me where I have to remove view?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_demo, container, true);

    listFragment = (VideoListFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);
    videoFragment = (VideoFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);

    videoBox = view.findViewById(R.id.video_box);
    closeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.close_button);

    videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    layout();

    return view;

}
```

**xml:**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.youtube.VideoListDemoActivity$VideoListFragment" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClickClose"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.youtube.VideoListDemoActivity$VideoFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
 </merge>
```

**layout():**

```
    private void layout() {
    boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    listFragment.getView().setVisibility(
            isFullscreen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    listFragment.setLabelVisibility(isPortrait);
    closeButton.setVisibility(isPortrait ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    if (isFullscreen) {
        videoBox.setTranslationY(0); 
        setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
        setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT,
                Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    } else if (isPortrait) {
        setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
        setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.BOTTOM);
    } else {
        videoBox.setTranslationY(0); 
        int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
        setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), screenWidth / 4, MATCH_PARENT);
        int videoWidth = screenWidth - screenWidth / 4
                - dpToPx(LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP);
        setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT);
        setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }
}
```

**logcat:**

```
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3389)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3260)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3205)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3181)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
02-18 22:18:56.431: E/AndroidRuntime(7936):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post `layout()`. Do you have any views initialized there?

Comment: This issue seems to be turning up a lot on SO in the past few days.

Comment: please post logcat completely

Comment: @DroidLearner I believe it's not a full logcat, right? Please look for Caused by... section with one of your files inside.

Comment: @nikis Unfortunately Its not showing the exact line.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_demo, container, true);
```

to

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_demo, container, false);
```

and read documentation why*.

*you must not attach fragment's view by yourself. You should only return it. And you can't use merge in this case because you can't return not attached merged view. FragmentManager will decide when to attach and remove fragment's view.

Comment: I'm using `merge` tag in Fragment, When I used `false` it was showing this message
`<merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true` so I set it to true.

Comment: You can't use <merge> if you return view for fragment. it won't work with merge.

Comment: so what's the better way to proceed further?

Comment: What do you mean? Change merge to some viewGroup that fits you. E.g. change <merge> to <FrameLayout>. Fragemnt's view should have root view.